# Adding Javascript To MSCRM Ribbon Workbench Button On Queue

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm-ribbon-workbench

I am trying to add a custom javascript method to a button in ribbon workbench, which has been created on the queue page.

I can get the button to show up fine. My problem is loading the javascript onto the queue page as it's a view not a form. Is this possible? Are there any work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular difference, insert the `JavascriptFunction` normally and it will be loaded and work.